# Returning axios promises from vuex action

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, es6-promise, vuex

I can't figure out, if it's a bad approach to have vuex actions returning axios promises like the example below. The reason why I do it, is because I need some values from the vuex state in the request. Can anyone tell me, if this is bad to do or totally fine? :)

```
/* Vuex action */
fetchSomething({ state }, id) {
  return getSomething(
    id,
    state.basket.shipping,
    state.basket.billing);
},

/* Method in vue component */
someMethod() {
  this.$store.dispatch('fetchSomething')
    .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean by "I need some values from the vuex state in the request"?

Comment: @LassiUosukainen I need some values saved in state as get parameters for the request

Comment: There are multiple ways to access the state before the request. Returning a promise from Vuex action however, is related to what happens after the request. It is not related to sending the request in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of doing this. The point of a Vuex action is to do the asynchronous job of retrieving the data and then to [mutate](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) the Vuex store.

Once the store has been mutated, you can [access it from your Vue component](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components). As Vuex is part of the Vue ecosystem it follows the same reactivity principles as Vue. If you need to execute something once you have retrieved the data you can set a watcher on the variable you are retrieving or more commonly just use it as a computed property.